# How to click on the Search button using Selenium and Python?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

[The screenshot of inspect code of this web page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cBxU.png). I just want to make a dynamic click on button "search" but I tried a lot of ways and there are always problems..new to web scraping

I have tried:

```
from selenium import webdriver

my_url = 'https://sbs.naic.org/solar-external-lookup/lookup?jurisdiction=AL&searchType=Company&companyStatus=AC'

driver = webdriver.Chrome('D:/chromedriver')

driver.get(my_url)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".btn.btn-primary").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='btn btn-primary' and @id='submitBtn']").click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".btn.btn-primary").click()
```

I just hope my pages can click the "search" button and go to the next page.

Comment: Please check if an iframe is present in the html structure above the element

Comment: @SameerArora Hi,Thanks for the advice, I am new to web scrap and I think it has iframe before it, I copy part of it:                                                              
<div _ngcontent-c3="" aria-label="Search" class="btn-group" role="group"><button _ngcontent-c3="" class="btn btn-primary" id="submitBtn" type="submit">Search</button>                                                               
<button _ngcontent-c3="" class="btn btn-secondary" id="resetBtn" type="button">Reset</button></div>

Comment: I have solved my problem now( element  = WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button[@class = 'btn btn-primary']")))) thanks anyone!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unable to access the [website](https://sbs.naic.org/solar-external-lookup/lookup?jurisdiction=AL&searchType=Company&companyStatus=AC). However the element with text as **Search** seems to be [Angular](https://angular.io/) element so to `click()` on the element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.btn-group[aria-label='Search']>button.btn.btn-primary#submitBtn"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='btn-group' and @aria-label='Search']/button[@class='btn btn-primary' and @id='submitBtn']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: made it! and can I have ask you another question? It's about select the maximum rows, I use "driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@formcontrolname='rowLimitField']/option[value= '50']").click() " but it shows unable to locate element and I can make sure the pathway it's right and there seems no iframe( I tried), it use the same link with search "https://sbs.naic.org/solar-external-lookup/lookup?jurisdiction=AL&searchType=Company&companyStatus=AC"

Comment: <select _ngcontent-c14="" formcontrolname="rowLimitField" id="rowLimitId" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid"><!----><option _ngcontent-c14="" value="10">10</option><option _ngcontent-c14="" value="25">25</option><option _ngcontent-c14="" value="50">50</option><option _ngcontent-c14="" value="100">100</option></select>

Comment: @Olly `//select[@formcontrolname='rowLimitField']/option[value= '50']` seems to be within `<select>` tag which you need to handle through `Select` class. Can you raise a new question as per your new requirement please?

Answer (score 0):

To handle dynamic element use `WebDriverWait` and then click on the element.

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//button[@class="btn btn-primary" and @id="submitBtn"]'))).click()
```

Please use following imports to execute above code.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes .click() does not work and I am unsure why. When that happens try .send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

I used Firefox and left my geckodriver executable path commented out in the code below. I am also locating the element by the id and not css selector.

```
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains


my_url = 'https://sbs.naic.org/solar-external-lookup/lookup?jurisdiction=AL&searchType=Company&companyStatus=AC'

driver = webdriver.Chrome('D:/chromedriver')
# driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\\Py\\geckodriver.exe');

driver.get(my_url)

click_search = driver.find_element_by_id("submitBtn")
click_search.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

Comment: Thanks a lott!!!! You also solved my problem in another wonderful method!